# Nested Models Wicked, render page

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, controller, show

I have nested models as, Boat `has_many :pictures`, Picture `belongs_to :boat`. I used the wicked gem to make steps after a user creates a boat. The last step is the picture step, where user can drag&drop the picture etc. It saves without a problem. But when user drops picture(s), it saves and renders the page again (jquery), to show what is added, so user can destroy the picture here.

But, it renders the page with empty pictures, however when I check  the database it saves. So it might because of the boat_steps `#show` action. But I could not find out. Because picture page did not belong to steps the finish wizard path is picture. But I would like to change it.  The reason I am refreshing the page is that I could not complete picture jquery. It is dropzonejs but if I leave out comments in the code. I can delete the photo from database but it sticks at the screen.

Here is the `boat_steps controller`

```
class BoatStepsController < ApplicationController
    include Wicked::Wizard


    before_action :logged_in_user
    steps :model, :pricing, :description, :features, :picture

    def show #PROBABLY I SHOULD CHANGE HERE
        @boat = current_user.boats.last
        @picture = @boat.pictures.new
        render_wizard
    end

    def update
        @boat = current_user.boats.last
        @picture = @boat.pictures.new
        case steps
            when :picture
                @picture.update(picture_params)
                render_wizard @picture
            else
            @boat.update(boat_params)
            render_wizard @boat
        end

    end


private

    def finish_wizard_path
        new_boat_picture_path(@boat, @picture)
    end



    def boat_params
      params.require(:boat).permit(:brand, :year, :model, :captained, :boat_type, :daily_price, :boat_length, :listing_tagline, :listing_description, :boat_category, :hull_material, :mast_material, :capacity, :sleeping_capacity, :private_staterooms, :fuel_type, :engine_horsepower, :fuel_capacity, :fuel_consumption, :draft)
    end

    def picture_params
      params.require(:picture).permit(:name, :brand_id, :image)
    end


end
```

Here is the `picture.html.erb`

```
<div class="container">

<%= form_for [@boat, @picture], html: { multipart: true, class: "dropzone", id: "picture-dropzone"} do |f| %>


      <p>

      <div class="fallback">
      <%= f.file_field :image %> 

      </div>    

      </p>

<% end %>

<p><%= link_to "Back to My Profile",  current_user %></p>


<% if @pictures.present? %>
    <% @pictures.each do |pic| %>
        </br>
        <%= pic.name %>
        <%= image_tag pic.image_url(:thumb).to_s  %>
        <%= link_to "edit", edit_boat_picture_path(@boat, pic) %> |
        <%= link_to 'Destroy', boat_picture_path(@boat, pic), confirm: 'Are you sure?', method: :delete %> | 
        </br>
    <% end %>
<% end %>



<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    // disable auto discover
    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

    // grap our upload form by its id
    $("#picture-dropzone").dropzone({
        // restrict image size to a maximum 5MB
        maxFilesize: 5,
        // changed the passed param to one accepted by
        // our rails app
        paramName: "picture[image]",

        acceptedFiles: "image/*", //CALISIYOR MU BILMIYORUm
        // show remove links on each image upload
        addRemoveLinks: false,
        // if the upload was successful
        success: function(file, response){
            // find the remove button link of the uploaded file and give it an id
            // based of the fileID response from the server
            //$(file.previewTemplate).find('.dz-remove').attr('id', response.fileID);
            //$(file.previewTemplate).find('.dz-remove').attr('boat_id', response.boatID);
            // add the dz-success class (the green tick sign)
            $(file.previewElement).addClass("dz-success");
            location.reload(); //HERE IT RELOADS THE PAGE
        },
        //when the remove button is clicked
        //removedfile: function(file){

            // grap the id of the uploaded file we set earlier
        //  var id = $(file.previewTemplate).find('.dz-remove').attr('id'); 
        //  var boat_id = $(file.previewTemplate).find('.dz-remove').attr('boat_id'); 
        //  // make a DELETE ajax request to delete the file
        //  $.ajax({
        //      type: 'DELETE',
        //      url: '/boats/' + boat_id + '/pictures/' + id,
        //      success: function(file){
        //           removeFile(file);

                    //location.reload();

        //      }
        //  });
        //}
    }); 
});



</script>
```

EDIT 1:

here is the picture controller

```
class PicturesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user
  before_filter :load_parent



  def new
    @picture = @boat.pictures.new
    @pictures = @boat.pictures.all 
  end

  def show
    @picture = @boat.pictures.find(params[:id])
  end


  def create

    @picture = @boat.pictures.new(picture_params)

    if @picture.save
    render json: { message: "success", fileID: @picture.id, boatID: @boat.id }, :status => 200

    else
      render json: { error: @picture.errors.full_messages.join(',')}, :status => 400

    end

  end


  def edit
    @picture = Picture.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @picture = @boat.pictures.find(params[:id])

    if @picture.update_attributes(picture_params)
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully updated picture."
      render 'index'
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy

    @picture = @boat.pictures.find(params[:id])
    if @picture.destroy
     #render json: { message: "File deleted from server" }
      redirect_to new_boat_picture_path(@boat, @picture)
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully destroyed picture."
    else
      render json: { message: @picture.errors.full_messages.join(',') }
    end
    #flash[:notice] = "Successfully destroyed picture."
    #redirect_to new_boat_picture_path(@boat, @picture)
    #redirect_to boat_pictures_path(@boat)
    #redirect_to boat_path(@boat)
  end




  private

    def picture_params
      params.require(:picture).permit(:name, :image)
    end

    def load_parent
     @boat = Boat.find(params[:boat_id])
    end





end
```

EDIT 2:

new show action is;

```
def show
        @boat = current_user.boats.last
        @picture = @boat.pictures.new
        @pictures = @boat.pictures.all

        render_wizard

    end
```

But then when I land on `....boat_steps/picture` url, it shows some empty pictures without nowhere. Why is that?

Here,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your controller you only assign `@picture` and in your view you refer to `@pictures` (which is not set afaik).

Comment: If I set it to @picture as you said, it throws an error `undefined method 'each' for #<Picture:0x007f835cb50158>`

Comment: @picture points to the new empty picture you use in the form, you want `@pictures = @boat.pictures`. Weird that you can't even read your own code anymore :)

Comment: haha tired a bit of looking at a screen. But now it shows empty pictures without doing anything. Page comes like the img I uploaded

Comment: I really appreciate for your help, would you be available to check the jquery?. That would save me tons of work to do

Comment: Arrg, ok so it creates a new picture for every step, so i should put case steps there..